# Problem with endpoint integration event ISAPI/Event/notification/alertStream

Tags: php, hikvision

I am integrating the HikVision DeepView camera via **ISAPI** and I encountered a problem, I did everything according to the documentation but I failed with the endpoint "**ISAPI/Event/notification/alertStream**"

I tried various methods and I managed to do it only with curl after browsing all the forums :), maybe not completely because when using curl it prints the result on the screen and I don't really know how to take it over by setting CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER to true it does not shorten the result after setting it to false it prints to the screen but I don't really know how to go about it.

Below is a simple curl call that allows me to download activated alarms

```
$ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://{}/ISAPI/Event/notification/alertStream');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, '{}}' . ':' . '{}}');

        $response = curl_exec($ch);

        if (curl_errno($ch)) {
            echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
        }

        curl_close($ch);

        return $response;
```

Script invoked in command symfony.

I am making a huge request for help :)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to save the data to the file, but from what I can see there is also binary data, an image and it will be difficult to extract anything from it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

this is the alertstream protocol
[image]

the --boundary represents the binary image data

Answer (score 0):

The notification API streams all notifications until you close the connection, this is why it's hard to use via curl.

Try this code instead: https://gist.github.com/ethaniel/72dae721ff770b7e1dcb0101589ed361